# Integer to roman conversion

Tags: fortran

As a little standard exercise, I wrote an integer to roman numerals converter in F03. The result looks already neat enough, for my standards, but I wonder whether it could be made snappier without sacrificing clarity.

```fortran
module mRomanStrings

  implicit none
  private
  character(len=*), parameter :: RM_CHARS  = "IVXLCDMvxlcdm_"
  integer         , parameter :: MAX_ORDER = len(RM_CHARS)/2-1
  character(len=4)            :: ROMAN_STRING(0:9,0:MAX_ORDER)
  logical                     :: mRomanStringsIsNotInitialized = .TRUE.
  public :: IntegerToRoman

contains

  function IntegerToRoman(i) result(rm)
    integer         , intent(in)  :: i
    character(len=:), allocatable :: rm
    integer :: n
    if( mRomanStringsIsNotInitialized ) call mRomanSring_init()
    rm = " "
    do n = min(MAX_ORDER,int(log(dble(i))/log(10.d0)+1.d-10)), 0, -1
       rm = trim(rm)//trim(ROMAN_STRING(mod(i/10**n,10),n))
    enddo
  end function IntegerToRoman

  subroutine mRomanSring_init()
    character :: a0, a1, a2, a3
    integer :: n
    do n = 0, MAX_ORDER
       a0 = " "
       a1 = RM_CHARS(2*n+1:2*n+1)
       a2 = RM_CHARS(2*n+2:2*n+2)
       a3 = RM_CHARS(2*n+3:2*n+3)
       ROMAN_STRING(0:9,n) = [&
            a0//a0//a0//a0, a1//a0//a0//a0, a1//a1//a0//a0, a1//a1//a1//a0, a1//a2//a0//a0, &
            a2//a0//a0//a0, a2//a1//a0//a0, a2//a1//a1//a0, a2//a1//a1//a1, a1//a3//a0//a0 ]
    enddo
    mRomanStringsIsNotInitialized = .FALSE.
  end subroutine mRomanSring_init
     
end module mRomanStrings

program ConvertIntegersToRoman
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
  use mRomanStrings
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  do i=1,10000
     write(OUTPUT_UNIT,"(i6,x,a)") i, IntegerToRoman(i)
  enddo
end program ConvertIntegersToRoman
```

Also, it looks like stackoverflow does not have any decent syntax highlight for fortran, let alone fortran2003. How comes? Emacs does...

Comment: If your code is working and you are just after comments about style and similar aspects, then you may want to consider the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Fortran isn't a popular tag there, but there certainly are some things to say about this code.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. It sounds like you would have feedback on the code; I look forward to it on Code Review